# Docker Apache/PHP Localhost keeps returning Error 404 For Sub-directories

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to use docker as a substitute to xampp. I have a directory structure with all my projects like so:

```
Work
  |- project_1
       |- public_html
  |- project_2
       |- public_html
  |- etc.
  |- httpd # this is where config files lie
```

I want to be able to deploy apache/php via docker and use the main "Work" folder as "htdocs". When I access a project via localhost (for e.g., http://localhost/project_1/public_html) it does *NOT* work (gives me a 404 error) while the same thing works perfectly fine on xampp and mamp. Also the directory index shows fine when I access http://localhost/project_1/; I've spent 4 days trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I haven't been able to. It seems like a problem with apache configuration perhaps as the same projects work with xampp and mamp.

The httpd folder has the following docker configuration files:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:

    php:
       build: .
       image: php:7.2-apache
       environment:
         ALLOW_OVERRIDE: 'true'
         DEBUG: 'true'
       ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "443:443"
       volumes:
         - ../:/var/www/html/
         - ./apache.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

**apache.conf:**

```
ServerName localhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerAlias localhost
  UseCanonicalName Off

  <Directory /var/www/html/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

COPY httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    xz-utils \
    build-essential \
    pkg-config \
    git-core \
    autoconf \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libsodium-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libpspell-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    imagemagick \
    subversion \
    python \
    g++ \
    curl \
    vim \
    wget \
    netcat \
    chrpath

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    iconv \
    -j$(nproc) sodium \
    opcache \
    curl \
    gd \
    mysqli \
    pdo \
    pdo_pgsql \
    pdo_mysql \
    pdo_sqlite \
    pspell \
    pgsql \
    soap \
    zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

WORKDIR /tmp
RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
RUN mv composer.phar /bin/composer
RUN chmod 700 /bin/composer

RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get autoremove -y
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/src/*

RUN a2enmod rewrite headers cache cache_disk expires vhost_alias userdir
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN service apache-htcacheclean start

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN usermod -G staff www-data

WORKDIR /var/www/html

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

EXPOSE 80
```

**httpd.conf:**

```
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost
ServerName localhost:80

Listen *:80

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User www-data
Group www-data
</IfModule>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </IfModule>

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
</IfModule>


Include conf/etc/httpd-mpm.conf
Include conf/etc/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
Include conf/etc/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include conf/etc/httpd-languages.conf
Include conf/etc/httpd-userdir.conf
Include conf/etc/httpd-info.conf
Include conf/etc/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include "conf/etc/httpd-proxy.conf"
Include "conf/etc/httpd-default.conf"

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/etc/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

Include conf/etc/httpd-ssl.conf

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
Include "conf/etc/httpd-ajp.conf"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess (for e.g. in /project_1/public_html directory):**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /project_1/public_html

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico|ttf|woff|woff2)$ [NC]

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I would really appreciate some help in this regard. I'm not very well versed in apache, and am just starting up with docker. Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you solve it? I'm stuck with the same problem now...